# UINavigationController – Override Back button action

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller in a navigation stack that represents a form that the user can fill out. The form has a handful of text fields and an "Apply" button at the bottom. If the user taps the native back button on the navigation bar after entering some information, I want the user to be prompted with a confirmation message: "Your changes have not been saved. Are you sure you want to go back?" But I'm not sure of a way I can "legally" override the action of the native back button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C you can override the navigationShouldPopOnBackButton function of the ViewController class to display a prompt message to the user

```
-(BOOL) navigationShouldPopOnBackButton {

// Do your logic

return NO;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `UINavigationItem` to the custom button in you `UIViewController` class.

After that you can execute your custom code in the `backButtonTouch:` function:

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", nil)
                                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                            target:self
                                                                            action:@selector(backButtonTouch:)];
```

Comment: Try and you'll see :-)